# Tag to Display MONTH and DAY

Tags: html, blackberry

Do we have any tag to display only the month and day in a mobile browser? It should be selectable by the user?

Or do we have any alternative to this for Blackberry Devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<time>` element. See [this summary](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/02/the-html5-time-element-is-back-and-better-than-ever/) for information, or [read the spec](http://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element)

Comment: Thanks, i know this how to display the static data but i need user to select a Day and Month as it is their option to choose

Comment: Well, it's tough to say without more information on your project, but have you considered something like jQuery UI's datepicker? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/